# profiler-report seems to be missing data

Tags: profiler

I'm trying to profile the usually excellent `find-things-fast` package to figure out why it's slow in my project.

I started profiling with `profiler-start`, executed the command that's slow (`ftf-find-file`), then immediately ran `profiler-report`.

This generated the following report:

```
Functions                                                 CPU samples  %
- command-execute                                                1770  88%
 - call-interactively                                            1770  88%
  - apply                                                        1770  88%
   - call-interactively@ido-cr+-record-current-command               1770  88%
    - apply                                                      1770  88%
     - #<subr call-interactively>                                1770  88%
      - funcall-interactively                                    1770  88%
       - ftf-find-file                                           1597  80%
        - ftf-project-files-alist                                1522  76%
         - ftf-project-files-hash                                1330  66%
          - let                                                  1330  66%
           - mapcar                                              1330  66%
            - #<lambda 0x5458e8e0>                               1024  51%
             - let*                                              1008  50%
                cons                                               24   1%
            + split-string                                        282  14%
         + maphash                                                192   9%
        + ido-completing-read                                      67   3%
       + next-line                                                 75   3%
       + ido-switch-buffer                                         41   2%
       + ido-switch-buffer-other-window                            38   1%
       + profiler-report                                           19   0%
+ ...                                                             145   7%
+ redisplay_internal (C function)                                  37   1%
+ timer-event-handler                                              26   1%
  undefined                                                         5   0%
+ gui-set-selection                                                 4   0%
  internal-echo-keystrokes-prefix                                   2   0%
```

The profiler report seems to blame the `let*` function within `ftf-project-files-hash`.

However, looking at that function:

```
(defun ftf-project-files-hash ()
  "Returns a hashtable filled with file names as the key and "
  (let ((default-directory (ftf-project-directory))
        (table (make-hash-table :test 'equal)))
    (mapcar (lambda (file)
              (let* ((file-name (file-name-nondirectory file))
                     (full-path (expand-file-name file))
                     (pathlist (cons full-path (gethash file-name table nil))))
                (puthash file-name pathlist table)))
            (split-string (ftf-project-files-string)))
    table))
```

It seems incredibly unlikely that `let*` is the slow part, but rather one of the functions called within that `let*`.

Why is `profiler-report` stopping at `let*` rather than telling me which component of that `let*` is slow? How can I dig deeper to find which exactly function is slow?

Comment: You might want to try adding a message before the `mapcar` section to see how big the list is, e.g., `(message "length: %s" (length (split-string (ftf-project-files-string))))`.  It may be that you are just dealing with a lot of stuff that needs to be processed.  It may also be that the function itself `ftf-project-files-string` is time consuming, and you might want to put a `measure-time` wrapper around it.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622296/emacs-timing-execution-of-function-calls-in-emacs-lisp

Comment: FYI, it does not appear that the `measure-time` macro throws the result of whatever it wraps (but I could be wrong), and the `mapcar` needs the result of `ftf-project-files-string` via (split-string ...).  Thus, you may want to put a separate `measure-time` statement with `(measure-time (ftf-project-files-string))` before the `mapcar` statement to do some debugging.  Of course, the profiler would then show double the time because that function would be called twice -- however, it is just for debugging to get a sense of the time cost.